# Bean variable not loading during unit test

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test some dao code in Spring Boot. Here is my class under test:

```
@Repository
public class AreaDao
{
    @Setter private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Setter private AreaMapper areaMapper;

    @Getter @Setter private String sql;

    public List getArea(String studioId)
    {
        String query = String.join(this.getSql(),studioId); // its throwing a NPE here 
        List areaList = jdbcTemplate.query(query, areaMapper);
        return areaList;
    }

}
```

The variable sql is loading from the bean xml:

```
<bean id="AreaDao" class="com.studio.dao.AreaDao">
         <property name="sql" value="SELECT DISTINCT(rGrp.GRP_N) AS AreaName 
                              FROM  DB.S_GRP rGrp 
                              WHERE rGrp.STR_I = " />
         <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="JdbcTemplate" />
         <property name="areaMapper" ref="AreaMapper" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="AreaMapper" class="com.studio.mapper.AreaMapper" />

   <bean id="JdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="DMDataSource" />
   </bean>
```

And here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AreaDaoTest {
    @Mock
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateMock;

    @Mock
    AreaMapper areaMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    AreaDao areaDao;

    private List areas;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        areas = new ArrayList();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetArea() throws SQLException {
        String studioId = "12345";
        when(jdbcTemplateMock.query(any(String.class), any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(areas);

        List areas = areaDao.getArea(studioId);

        Assert.assertNotNull(areas);
        Assert.assertTrue(areaDao.getSql().contains(studioId));
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the test its throwing a NPE in loading the sql var from the bean xml. I tried adding @ContextConfiguration or just @Autowired on the dao in the test but it didn't work. Also how can I verify in the test if its loading a value?
Appreciate your help.